# Error con mysqli Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) base de datos php

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

Mi base de datos me está arrojando este error en el codigo php de mi carpeta "core" y me indica que tengo que definir el usuario y contraseña correspondientes para que pueda cargar pero no sé en que parte y de qué forma se hace, porfavor ayuda

```
<?php
class Conectar{
public static $driver;
public static $host, $user, $pass, $database, $charset;
public static $conexion=NULL;


function __construct($driver, $host, $user, $pass, $database, $charset) {
    

}
 
public static function conexion() {

    $database_cfg  = require 'config/database.php';
    self::$driver  =$database_cfg["driver"];
    self::$host    =$database_cfg["host"];
    self::$user    =$database_cfg["user"];
    self::$pass    =$database_cfg["pass"];
    self::$database=$database_cfg["database"];
    self::$charset =$database_cfg["charset"];
    
    if(self::$driver=="mysql" || self::$driver==null)
    {
         
        $conexion=new mysqli(self::$host, self::$user, self::$pass, self::$database);
         mysqli_set_charset($conexion, self::$charset);        
         if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
               echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
               exit();
        }else{
               return $conexion;  
         } 
     }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que le estás intentando asignar a una variable el resultado una instrucción (no función) `require`. [Lectura recomendada](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php).

Cambia esta línea

```php
$database_cfg  = require 'config/database.php';
```

Por

```php
require 'config/database.php';
```

Obviamente para que la variable `$database_cfg` funcione, dentro de **database.php** debes tener algo así:

```php
<?php
$database_cfg = array(
    'driver'=>'mysql',
    'host'=>'localhost',
    // ... etc
);
```